# WPF Postpone control rendering

Tags: .net, wpf

I need to postpone rendering of a part of the view till ViewModel's property gets some value. I tried to set `Visible = Hidden` to some container but it didn't work: UI is rendered anyway (but is not displayed). I guess the solution is to use `DataTemplate`. I tried the following:

```
<ContentControl>
    <DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding DataContext.State}" Value="0"></DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>

        <TextBlock>Yes</TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>
</ContentControl>
```

But it didn't work. Please hint me the way of right `DataTemplate` usage (or some alternative ways to solve this problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tricky problem here, but here is my take.

I'll assume that you are waiting for the `State` property to be initialized. Add a boolean property to your `ViewModel`, namely `IsStateReady`, firing `PropertyChanged`:

```
private bool isStateReady;

public bool IsStateReady
{
   get { return isStateReady; }
   set 
   {
      isStateReady = value;
      OnPropertyChanged("IsStateReady");
   }
}
```

Then, define your control with a `Trigger` setting the `Template` property only when `IsStateReady` is true:

```
        <Control>
            <Control.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Control}">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsStateReady, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Template">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ControlTemplate>
                                        <!-- your template here-->
                                    </ControlTemplate>
                                </Setter.Value>
                            </Setter>
                        </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Control.Style>
        </Control>
```

This should do the trick for you